# Oracle create link between local xe and remote database in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-connection, listener, tnsnames

I'm trying to create a link between my local database and my oracle 11g school database. I've finished the link creating between two databases and I tried to run a simple statement from my local database and to see if I can access the data from the remote database. However, there was an error message keep showing on the output section.

[image]

I've tried to google the error, but none of the solutions helps.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: There's something incorrect in your connection definition for the database link. The service_name you specified doesn't exist on the remote system. If you have access to the remote server, run "lsnrctl services" from the command line to get a list of available services, or get the correct service_name value from the DBA.

Comment: What do you have within the `TNSNAMES.ORA` file in the `CONNECT_DATA` section ? If it's `SID`, then replace with `SERVICE_NAME`.